# pg_search + Rails - Prevent redirect to page with search results if there wasnt't any of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg-search

Appreciate for a help. I'm using Rails 4, ruby 2.2.3 and PostgreSQL 9.6. 
I have website with search based on pg_search, and it works perfectly with multiple models:

```
/app/models/event.rb:

multisearchable against: [:title, :subtitle]
```

Both searchable models and search controller setted up very simple by official manuals.

```
/app/controllers/results_controller.rb:

class ResultsController < FrontendController
  def index
    @search_results = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
  end
end
```

And my results view:

```
/app/views/results/index.slim:

.search-results-wrap
  - @search_results.each do |pg_search_document|
    #showing title of each result, etc.
```

Now I need to improve it by checking before redirect to page with search results - are there any results at all? I mean, there isn't much sense in redirecting if there are no results and it will be more smart to just show a flash message(or something like that) "sorry, no results" on current page.

Is there possible ways to do it?

Comment: yeah, of course it is possible. if it wouldn't be possible, you should not even think about it -)) post some code -))

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. It isn't clear and is broad.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (<your search function>).empty?
  flash.now[:notice] = "No, results"
  render '<your current search page>'
else
  redirect_to '<your search results page>'
end
```

Comment: well maybe, but I didn't see any info about defining search function in PgSearch manuals. I added some code, maybe it will be clearer to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the model approach

Article.rb

```
  def self.search(query)
    if query.present?
      search_for(query) # takes you to your search method
    else
      # No query? Return all records, newest first.
      Article.all.order('updated_at DESC')
    end
  end

pg_search_scope :search_for,
  ...
```

Article index or search search results page

```
- if @articles.present?
  # Show articles
- else
  p No articles found. Use other queries
```

Controller

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.search(params[:query])
```

Best practice is to always tell the user whether he is getting any results or if he made a typo or needs to look things up differently.

Comment: Well, the point is not to define was there any text to search but to check before the forwarding to results page - do rails have any results to show and if not - avoid redirecting.

But I must admit you're right - I surely must add some code to check if there any text to search. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, it seems to me multisearch is more complicated than I think. What I did wrong here? Didn't see any flash.now.

def self.multisearch(query)
    if query.present?
      multisearch(query)
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "alert! no query at all!"
    end
  end